# LoopBack WARNING: id property cannot be changed from to

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm using LoopBack with MongoDB as my datasource and have a simple model defined as:

```
{
    "name": "restaurant",
    "plural": "restaurants",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": false,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

I have an auto-migrate script in my `/server/boot` which creates two simple test data.
After that when I try to update one of those entries with PUT request using LoopBack's API explorer I get a warning
`WARNING: id property cannot be changed from ... to ... for model:restaurant in 'before save' operation hook`
`WARNING: id property cannot be changed from ... to ... for model:restaurant in 'loaded' operation hook`
and redundant `id` field (same as mongo's _id field) is created in DB.

I was able to prevent the creation of the redundant `id` field by setting `idInjection` to `false` and defining another property in model definition as:

```
"_id": {
  "id": true,
  "generated": true
}
```

However, I still get the warning after doing a PUT request from LoopBack's API explorer.

How should the mongo's `_id` field be defined in model definition properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the id by adding a "hidden" field to your model JSON. And add "id" to the array to be hidden.

```
{
"name": "restaurant",
"plural": "restaurants",
"hidden": [
    "id"
 ],
"base": "PersistedModel",
"idInjection": false,
"options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": true
    },
    "address": {
        "type": "string",
        "required": true
    }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
```

}